# How to get .NET MVC to bind POST parameters when Content-Type is text/plain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cors

I have an [IE8/IE9 CORS request using XDomainRequest](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) of type POST coming into an ASP .NET MVC 3 web application. The linked blog post indicates that:

> Only text/plain is supported for the request's Content-Type header

Now, since the Content-Type is `text/plain` and this is outside my control, the MVC framework will not bind the `POST` content parameters. It only seems to bind them when the `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I cannot read the parameters from the `Request` object either.

I need to find a way for MVC to bind these parameters. I thought about trying to modify the `Content-Type` of the request on `Application_BeginRequest` but this didn't work.

***How can I get the MVC Framework to bind the POST parameters when the `Content-Type` is `text/plain`?***

---

**Update**

I believe the parameters will be available through the [Request.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property. I'm looking for a way to generically bind these parameters using the MVC Framework default binding. I'd prefer not to have to write a model binder for every model in my project.

Comment: My initial idea would be to create a custom model binder. But since you say that you can't even access the Request object, I'm not sure if this would be an option.

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta I've searched through the `Request` object in debug mode, and can't find the POST content params. Fiddler is showing them coming in though. Maybe I'm not looking in the right place on the `Request` object? They're not in the `Headers` or `Params` collections.

Comment: If you do Request["yourParamName"] it is null?

Comment: Did you check HttpContext object?

Comment: @Romias yes Request["yourParamName"] is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if:

- You really are sending a x-www-form-urlencoded. Maybe you are sending a JSON?
- The response includes Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

I tried the following and it worked:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.ContentType) && Context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            Context.Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        }
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
}
```

**Note:** For better modularity, you may want to implement Application_BeginRequest as a HTTP module and CORS (the Access-Control-Allow-Origin) as an ActionFilter

Answer (score 1):

No real experience in this subject, but here you can see some approaches thar could help you.

**Check this SO Questions and workarounds:**

- [Cors, Web Api, IE8, Post Complex Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989088/cors-web-api-ie8-post-complex-data)
- [Posting text/plain as a complex object in WebAPI with CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621112/posting-text-plain-as-a-complex-object-in-webapi-with-cors)

**Here is how it can be done in ASP.NET WebAPI:**

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I have already seen these links, they are for Web API. I am looking for a way to do it in regular MVC 3.